# non-blocking assignment to a variable twice in a always block gives unexpected answer

Tags: verilog, hdl

I'm trying to write a Verilog module and a section of code is something like this:

```
input wire [7:0] data_in
reg [199:0] buffer;
.
.
.
always @(posedge clk) begin
    buffer[119:112] <= data_in; //place data_in to a specific part of buffer
    buffer <= buffer << 8; //logical left shift the buffer
end
```

but the problem is the first line of always block is ignored (after each clk posedge)! in another word, `data_in` doesn't place in `buffer[119:112]` and buffer always remain `200'b0`!

the first question is what is the the cause?
and the second question is how can i do that what i want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to look at this from the point of view of the hardware design. `always @(posedge clk)` represents a flop. The only thing it does, is saving values at the clock edge. The data itself is prepared with some combinatorial logic before. In your case, assigning data_in to some bits as well, as the shift are the parts of the combinatorial world.
Saying that, you can write your model as the following:

```
   reg [199:0] buffer_in, buffer_shifted;
   reg [7:0]   data_in;
   reg         clk;   

   always @* begin
      buffer_in = buffer;
      buffer_in[119:112] = data_in;
      buffer_shifted = buffer_in << 8;
   end
   always @(posedge clk)
     buffer <= buffer_shifted;
```

First two statements in the above always block are really the same as the following

```
      buffer_in = {buffer[199:120], data_in[7:0], buffer[111:0]};
```

And now you can collapse all of this and even move it to the statement which models the flop itself. The nature of these statements will still be the same, combinatorial logic, but you can get rid of intermediate variables:

```
   always @(posedge clk)
     buffer <= {buffer[199:120], data_in[7:0], buffer[111:0]} << 8;
```

**Adding a testcase**

```
module top;
   reg [7:0]   data_in;
   reg         clk;
   reg [199:0] buffer;
   
   always @(posedge clk)
     buffer <= {buffer[199:120], data_in[7:0], buffer[111:0]} << 8;
   
   initial begin
      clk = 0;
      buffer = 0;
      data_in = 4'h1;
      #13
        data_in = 4'h2;
   end
   
   always 
     #5 clk = ~clk;
   
   initial 
     #20 $finish;
   
   always @*
     $display("%3t> %h_%h", $time, buffer[199:112], buffer[111:0]);
endmodule
```

Comment: Thank you. but I think your final answer didn't work in my case, in the sense that data_in doesn't placed in buffer and a empty buffer shift every cycles. you can see this image of my simulation that shows data_in is never placed in buffer. i used `always @(posedge clk) buffer <= {buffer[199:120], data_in[7:0], buffer[111:0]} << 8;`  [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1q-ukfW67i_BqgPcg30VLk3eegAmocEi6/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: @SayedSaeedJazaeri this means that you have a different issue as well, not captured in your example. You can ask a separate question if you cannot figure it out.

Comment: @SayedSaeedJazaeri I added a testcase to my answer. you can play with it.,

Answer (score 0):

For non-blocking assignments in the same process, the first assignment is overwritten; the last assignment wins.

Use two registers to accomplish the functionality of both assignments.

Variable buffer_2 will contain the aggregate result of both operations.

```
input wire [7:0] data_in
reg [199:0] buffer;
reg [199:0] buffer_2;
.
.
.
always @(posedge clk) begin
    buffer[119:112] <= data_in; //place data_in to a specific part of buffer
    buffer_2 <= buffer << 8; //logical left shift the buffer
end
```

Comment: All that was needed is reversing the two NBAs statements. No need for two buffers.

Comment: @Mikev thank you. I understood my first problem. but about your suggestion for implementation, you are using two buffers in which that is a waste of resources (suppose the buffer contains a lot of bytes and our FPGA is limited :) )